# Upload multiple files by clicking file upload again

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

How can I appended files to be uploaded when user clicks on the input upload button again?

I have no problems with selecting multiple files to upload as I have set the `multiple` attribute. It is just when user wants to add more files to be uploaded.

Here's a scenario to better illustrate.

1. User clicks on file upload button.
2. User selects multiple files to upload.
3. User clicks on file upload button again.
4. User selects more files to upload.
5. User clicks on the upload to server button to upload files on the server.

Upon checking the request, it seems that the last batch are the only ones being uploaded. Shouldn't it be appended?

Comment: I recommend you to use multiple file upload buttons. Like second and third button.

Comment: Natively the upload element only uploads the **latest** selected batch of element

Comment: Have a look at some plugin like: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: It is similar to how this works https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html. User can add files that gets appended and then hit the start upload button to upload all. I already made my own plugin and would like the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [blueimp/jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

> Multiple file upload:
>   Allows to select multiple files at once and upload them simultaneously.

You can also upload in serie like you are looking for. [See the demo](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html).

Comment: Yeah, similar to how that works. But I made my own plugin and would like the same functionality.

Comment: @basagabi well, if you would like the same functionalities, I would suggest you take something that is already proven, even if you are only interested in 5% of the functionalities.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but there are some plugins that are not suitable base on the requirements. Aside from that, it will also be a good learning to know how to make such functionality.

Comment: @basagabi Certainly